# Generate new page after slug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a NextJS application, currently I am using **getStaticPaths** and **getStaticProps** to build the static pages, doing the necessary requests for them.

So I want to build all the pages following this url: `challenge/[slug]/` and for each slug that corresponds to an id I want to have a applications page like this: `challenge/[slug]/applications` to archive this I builded a file [...slug] inside `/pages/challenge`

**Inside that file I have the following code to handle the static generation:**

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response: any = await getPrograms()

  const paths = response.results.map(result => {
    return { params: { slug: [result.id.toString()] } }
  })

  return { paths, fallback: true }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await getProgram(params.slug[0])
  const stages = await getStages(params.slug[0])

  return { props: { program: res, stages: stages }, revalidate: 1 }
}
```

this solution works for **/challenge/[slug]**, but the **/challenge/[slug]/applications** receives a 404, how can I render a specific application page for the slug?

I tried to add a second position to the slug array, but if I do it I can just render **/challenge/[slug]/applications** and not **/challenge/[slug]**

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You need to create a **FOLDER** named `[slug]`. Then, Create a **FILE** named `applications.js`. Lastly, copy and paste that code into this page.

```
__ challenge
  |__ [slug]
     |__ applications
```

In this page you can get or set `slug` as your desired parameter.